# Пауза в цикле С# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток, сообщество. Помогите начинающему программисту на С# WindowsForms.
Есть задание: написать программу для подсчета

> X=x1+x2+...+xn, xn=zn^3-bn+an^2/tan(Bettan).

На форме `Form1` я ввожу `n`, и хочу чтобы для каждого `xn` открывалась форма для ввода `z,a,b,betta`. Решил сделать в цикле:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Input.Show();
    X[i] = Z[i] * Z[i] * Z[i] - B[i] + (A[i] * A[i]) / Math.Tan(Betta[i]);
}
```

Но цикл открывает сразу n форм, это не удобно. Паузу в цикле я тоже реализовать не смог. Вопрос: "Как мне сделать так чтобы формы открывались по одной? Или может подскажите, как сделать удобный ввод данных другим способом?" Заранее спасибо всем кто откликнется.

Comment: `Input` - это что у вас?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи и ввода значений `z, a, b, betta` в цикле по очереди вы можете использовать (почти) любую форму, унаследованную от стандартной с полями (полем ввода), вызывая её через `ShowDialog()` а не через `Show()`.
Например, если ваша форма `Input` унаследована от стандартной формы, то вызывайте ее так:

```
Input.ShowDialog();
```

Можно расширить функционал и обрабатывать какие-то дополнительные условия, если еще и обработать результат такого вызова, например, так:

```
if (Input.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {.......//Что-то делаем} 
  else if (if (Input.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel))
    {
       //Пользователь нажал отмену или просто закрыл форму
    }
```

Если вызывать именно `ShowDialog()`, то ваша форма вызывается как модальная форма, т.е. в вашем случае программа не продолжит свою работу (цикл), пока форма висит на экране и пользователь не закрыл ее тем или иным способом.

Вместо такой формы можно использовать `InputBox`:

```
string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "DefaultValue", -1, -1);
```

Или реализовать свою форму, как, например, предлагается сделать это [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427121/6935496).

*P.S. Я бы не использовал такой подход, разве что в целях отладки, да и то, если **n** достаточно невелико, а то если оно, к примеру, будет 50 или 100, то пользователь замучается вводить значения. Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.*

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли)